# how to recover partition from harddisk

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

I have a 500 gb internal laptop harddisk.I have windows 7 in one of the four partitions. The system didn't boot so I used pendrive linux to boot ubuntu from usb. After booting using ubuntu I'm able to see My four partitions but only one is mounted, and when I try to mount I get an error saying "Unable to access Voulume".

I'm not able to boot using windows, worse, I'm not able to recover my files.

Help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use check disk from Linux, most probably corrupted file system.
If this did not help, you may have a hardware problem in the HDD.

Comment: I'm able to access one partition. But the other 3 seems to have some issues in mounting.